# angular 5 bootstrap 4 compatibility

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I search in internet and tried all the solution proposed but the problem not resolved,help me please :( :'(

[version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJCOx.png)

[problem displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9StA.png)

Comment: Please add the relevant information in your pictures as text to your question

Comment: this is my first question in this site: p how can I do that

Comment: You can paste images directly into the post (use "edit" option)

Comment: it's look like you have tried use ng-bootstrap, but you have a bootstrap.css version 3. Just follow the instruction on page https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started to install ng-bootstrap and add in your angular-cli.json the bootstrap.min.css version 4 in "styles" section

Comment: this response can guide me to solution i think there is a new version of bootstrap I will try it thanks <3

Comment: The problem  resolved thank you :) <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thaaanks

I solved the problem by this dependencies 
[new dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl0SR.png)